# Why can't I use the "Any" as a name in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

While trying to define an **Any()** function like python's, I found that I couldn't name anything "Any".

Attempting to name a Function, Sub, Const, or variable `any` will throw a syntax error and the VBA IDE will highlight it.

I know **any** not a particularly great name, but why is it throwing a syntax error?  The only reason I could think of was that it might be a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx), but it's not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VBA ([Visual Basic for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)) is *not* VB.NET, even though they share the same "Visual Basic" monikor and a similar syntax. (The linked documentation is for VB.NET, not VBA.)

VB6 and VBA *in* Microsoft Office (eg. Access, Excel) handles [`Any` as a reserved word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx), and it cannot be used as an identifier:

> You might also encounter errors if you use a reserved word to name a control, an object, or a variable. The error messages you receive don't necessarily tell you that a reserved word is the cause of the problem.

In VB.NET, however, there is no problem using `Any` as a variable name or other identifier:

```
Dim Any as String = "Hello world!"    'works just fine in VB.NET
```

Comment: In addition:  "Any" was reserved in VB6 as well as VBA (for all Office products).

Comment: Seems like I was just referring to the wrong documentation.  I'm having a hard time finding the correct one.  This was for excel-vba.

Comment: Yeah, MS is really good about keeping official VB6 stuff in hard to find places. If you type Any in a code module, put your cursor in the word and hit F1, you'll be taken to the Declare help file. There it will say that you can use "As Any" in an API call when you don't know the data type to be returned. It's the Variant of API data types. That's why it's reserved.

Answer (score 0):

To get an updated information to this question and comments, Microsoft states on their own page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/as-any-is-not-supported-in-declare-statements:

> The Any data type was used with Declare statements in Visual Basic 6.0
>   and earlier versions to permit the use of arguments that could contain
>   any type of data. Visual Basic supports overloading, however, and so
>   makes the Any data type obsolete.